# Formating Ubuntu installer on a usb stick

Tags: usb, format

I have a USB stick with 8 GB and I want to put the ubuntu installer on it. Once I am done installing Ubuntu on my computer can I format the USB stick so the Ubuntu installer is not on there anymore? If you can please tell me how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have installed Ubuntu, open 'GParted' (it may be called Disks), delete the partition, and reformat your USB stick to FAT32 - but be careful that you do not format your hard drive. There is a guide [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17001/how-to-format-a-usb-drive-in-ubuntu-using-gparted/).